# How do you use a for loop to read a file and print each line of a file in a certain format

Tags: python

I need the below text file to print like below:

admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program,10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks , Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No
peter, data storage, Store data into a secure database and run monthly reports, 25 Jun 2022, 2022-03-10, No

Needs to print each line in the file in this format out in this format:

---

Task:                  Assigned initial tasks
Assigned to:           admin
Date assigned:         10 Oct 2019
Due date:              25 Oct 2019
Task Complete?         No
Task description:
Use taskManager.py to assign member

---

This is the code that I wrote but I cant seem to figure out run the loop correctly:

```
 with open("tasks.txt", "r") as f:
           list_string = f.read().split(", ")
           print("______________________________")
           for line in list_string:
              print(f"Task:\t\t\t {line}\nAssigned to:\t\t\t {line}\nDate assigned:\t\t\t {line}\nDue date:\t\t\t {line}\nTask complete:\t\t\t {line}\nTask description:\n{line}")                 
              print("____________________________")
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Are you getting any output? If that is not desired, what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: It would help if you show a sample of the input file

Comment: Task: Assigned initial tasks Assigned to: admin Date assigned: 10 Oct 2019 Due date: 25 Oct 2019 Task Complete? No Task description: Use taskManager.py to assign member

Comment: The expected outcome is that at each point where the line split by a comma and a space that string will print out as Task: Register user (a newline) Assigned to: admin (a new line) due date: 22 Jun 2022 (new line) and so on and son until all the lines of the file are read

Answer (score 0):

The general mechanism for reading line oriented data would be:

```
with open('<your input file>') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    pass # process each line here
```

Comment: The contents of the input file are below: admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program,10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No admin, Assign initial tasks , Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No peter, data storage, Store data into a secure database and run monthly reports, 25 Jun 2022, 2022-03-10, No